# JwtDecoder prevents application from building

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jwt

I have an application build error, It is configured by default and I am extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in a class called DisabledSecurityConfig. I keep getting this

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Method springSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' in your configuration.